# creating text effects (like flash) using javascript in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

Can somebody suggest me how to create text effects (like we can create in flash) in HTML 5 using javascript/jquery. And also the custom font for whatever text is appearing there? Is it possible? any example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really need to look at Css3 for text based effects. But if you want to create full animations then Canvas would be your HTML5 tech of choice.

Try taking a look here:

http://canvas-text.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/animation.html

http://aaronwinborn.com/blogs/aaron/cuf%C3%B3n-alternative-sifr-image-replacement

Cufon draws fonts onto canvas so you could then animate them with javascript.

http://www.8bitrocket.com/2010/05/15/html-5-canvas-creating-gaudy-text-animations-just-like-flash-sort-of/

http://speckyboy.com/2009/11/16/20-easy-to-use-jquery-text-effects-and-animations/

here:

http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-examples-of-stunning-css3-text-effects

here:

http://www.addictivefonts.com/various/css3/css3-text-effects/

and here:

http://code.google.com/webfonts